# Stability of an equlilibrium point

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, dynamical-systems, nonlinear-system

Analyze the stability of equilibrium point $\bar{x}=0$ of the system: (Does it have more than one equilibrium point?)

$\left\{ \begin{array}{lcc}
             \dot{x_1}=x_1(a-bx_2)  \\
             \\  \dot{x_2}=x_2(-c+dx_1)
             \end{array}
   \right.$

I tried this by using Bendixson criteria or a Liaponouv's function but I don't know how to approach this. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @MrYouMath when $a, b, c, d >0$ this is a predator-prey model.